# Skyrim SE - Being a Mage and a Werewolf

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

So, I'm a High Elf mage in the game right now and I completed the Companions questline to fuel my curiosity and was stunned when I found out there were Werewolves. My strategy with being a Werewolf was to turn into one when I had no more potions or magicka that I could use. Is this a good strategy?

Comment: This question is almost guaranteed to elicit opinionated answers, which makes it off topic for this site. As you can see from the first two answers, both are entirely opinion based. My opinion is a good bow and high enough archery is all you need. Others would say differently. This site is more about questions that have a single objective answer to them. Hence the downvoting, and my vote to close it.

Comment: Sorry, I literally just joined this site right before I asked the question, didn't know that opinions aren't allowed.

Comment: Its all good, no worries. Check out the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help), it has everything you need to know about what's accepted and not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Good and bad strategies are somewhat subjective, but I have had good luck with a similar strategy (archer/werewolf, transform when the time for sniping is over).

The issue you'll run into is if you don't focus enough on werewolf, you might have trouble getting your perks up to where they stay competitive late game.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually planning to grind up my Werewolf perks later but I think I'll pick up alchemy late game so I can fix my magicka problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is a fine strategy. I personally never cared for the werewolf transformation but to each their own.

Usually a melee build works better for the werewolf build because some of the skills apply while you're transformed.

As a mage, though, you might be better off kiting until your magicka comes back.

Comment: I usually don't kite because I can just use Highborn to kill the enemies in that area, but I'll be sure to give it a try. :)

Comment: @Loop And don't be afraid to experiment. Skyrim is a VERY forgiving game. Create fresh saves when you change something big so you can always go back. Enjoy the game!